# How to superimpose masked part of image to a new image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm really sorry for this basic question, but I'm new to OpenCV and image processing in general, and couldn't figure this out after fiddling around for a while.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a transparent PNG image:

[image: Original image]

I created a binary mask out of this with the transparent region being black and the object being white:

[image: Binary mask]

Now, I have another image like this, having the same dimensions:

[image: Patterned image]

Now, I wish to superimpose the white masked part from the first image (the actual object) onto this image. How do I do this?

Comment: c++ syntax has a mat.copyTo(mat, mask) function. Not sure about the python syntax. Make sure that both images have same size though, or use subimages.

Comment: May be the blog-post here https://sourcecodezoneseven.blogspot.com/2019/05/opencv-create-transparent-background.html might helpful, which is also doing the similar thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that we have numpy arrays at hands here, we can first extend the mask to three dimensions:

```
# Case 1: original mask is OpenCV mask (foreground values 255)
mask = np.dstack([(mask > 0)]*3)
# Case 2: original mask is already boolean
mask = np.dstack([mask]*3)
```

And then copy the image over using the mask:

```
np.copyto(background, foreground, where=mask)
```

Comment: The shape of my mask is (300,300), while source1 and source2 are both (300,300,3). This gives me an error: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (300,300) (300,300,3)".

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to share the general idea. It works like this with C++ OpenCV Mat objects, but in Python with ndarrays you have to do a bit more. You can extend the mask in the third dimension. I have python code for this that I can post later.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you so much! I'll try extending the dimension of the mask.

Comment: I use `np.dstack` to extend my masks. This should work: `mask = np.dstack([mask]*3)`, or simply `mask = np.dstack((mask, mask, mask))`. But I will edit my answer to provide even better solution using np alone.

Comment: For extending the mask, I did this: `_, extended_mask = np.broadcast_arrays(source1, mask[..., None])`. It worked. I'll try out your code too to see if I can make it faster. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Thanks @ypnos! Is it also possible to use `np.copyto` to superimpose a mask with transparency? For example, if we want the overboard overimposed on the background with some degree of transparency in the sense of RGBA images

Comment: No, this method cannot be used for alpha composition. But there's a good OpenCV tutorial avaliable for that: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
import cv2

# Load images
bg     = cv2.imread('bg.png')                                                                 
obj = cv2.imread('object.png')                                                         
mask   = cv2.imread('mask.png')                                                             

# Zero background where we want to overlay
bg[mask>0]=0                                                                              

# Add object to zeroed out space
bg += obj*(mask>0)                                                                     

cv2.imwrite('result.png',bg)
```

[image]